# How do i get IndexOf Removed Item from ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

i want to override my `ObservableCollection` with an Undo/Redo functionality 
but how do i get the IndexOf the OldItem because it is still -1

and it looks like there is non CollectionChanging() implementation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a remove operation the `OldStartingIndex` property of the `NotifyCollectionChangeEventArgs` will tell you the index the item held in the collection before it was removed.

For example

```
var col = new ObservableCollection<string>();
col.Add("hello");
col.Add("world");
col.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.OldStartingIndex);
col.RemoveAt(1);
col.RemoveAt(0);
```

This will print out

```
1
0
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution for me is to keep a separate List for your data and let the `ObservableCollection<int>` keep the sequence index, this will make it much light weighted. You can have a `List<ObservableCollection<int>>` as a history cache, and dynamically update the current position in the list, (consider this as navigation history). Be aware that it is dependent on your performance requirement, if your data is very lengthy, this is problematic, and this is easier to implement otherwise.